# Executing imagemagick commands with java gives no output

Tags: java, command-line, command, imagemagick, path-variables

I am writing a java aplication that edits images using **imagemagick** commands;
However, the comands do not work and I am getting no output from them;
Actually, the comand identify is not recognized and I get `CreateProcess error=2`;
This seems odd, because the **imagemagick** instalation folder is included in my Path variable.

Here's my code:

```
     public class Test {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Runtime ru = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process p = null;
        try {
            //I've added this as a bouns, this should not be neccessary(methinks)
            String[] s = {"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16"};
            String[] cmd = {"convert", "acc-logo.jpg","-flip", "edited.jpg"};
            p = ru.exec(cmd,s);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader ina = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = ina.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in the path to the executable, and the `Runtime.exec()` call is having problems with it. Use `ProcessBuilder` instead; it handles spaces in arguments much more easily.